# Error in an if statement not reponding to clauses

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I need to make a file which will write basic statistics questions for a question bank.

I wrote a script in r in which in each cycle of a for statement a data set is created and then converted to a single frequency vector. Then a question is selected with the following pattern: "q1" in cycle 1, "q2" in cycle 2, "q3" in cycle 3, "q1" in cycle 4, "q2" in cycle 5, etc. This is performed by an if statement.

The questions and answers are written into a file named with the date.

The problem is that the answers are wrong, the program sometimes keeps the last value and I can't figure it out why. This is a sample output:

The code I'm using is the following:

```
Aaa <- function() 
{ 
  Qt  <<- readline(prompt="Iterations:")  
  } 

Aaa() 

##### Create file to sink to:#################
Date.<-Sys.Date()
Date.<-format(Date., format="%Y%m%d")
Archivo<- paste(Date.,".txt",sep="")

##### Create iterations ######################

sink(Archivo, append=FALSE)
cat("PRUEBA")
cat("\n")
sink(NULL)

for (i in 1:Qt){
  j<-(i/3-trunc(i/3))*3  

sink(Archivo, append=TRUE)

##### Generación de variables y cálculos #####  

  x<-round(rnorm(400,55,12),0)

  cuts<-seq(10.5,100.5,9)
  x<-x[x>10]
  x<-x[x<101]
  Table.<-hist(x,breaks = cuts,plot = FALSE)$counts
  Class. <- sample(3:9,1)

if (j==0) {
  Qstn <- paste("What is cum sum for class ",Class.,"?",sep="")
  Answ<-cumsum(Table.)[Class.]
} else if (j==1) {
  Qstn <- paste("What % of data corresponds to class ",Class.,"?",sep="")
  Answ<-Table.[Class.]/sum(Table.)*100 
} else if (j==2) {
  Qstn <- paste("Cummulative percent for class ",Class.,"?",sep="")
  Answ<-cumsum(Table.)[Class.]/length(x)*100 
}

##### List of questions #####
  cat(Table.,sep=", ")
    cat("\nQuestion ",i,":\n", 
      Qstn,"?\n",
    "=",Answ,"\n",
    "\n\n\n",
    sep="")

sink(NULL)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question led by Jan's comments.

Problem: When the j variable is supposed to be `2`, the if function `if (j==2)` returns  `FALSE`...

Observation:
`j<-((1:5)/3-trunc((1:5)/3))*3` should return `[1] 0 1 2 0 1` but it seems to be returning the same but unnoticeably UNROUNDED.

Solution:
I changed it to `j<-round((i/3-trunc(i/3))*3,1)` and it worked!

Comment: Still trying to figure out who Jan is.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a data-object named `Qt` an populate it with a character vector then is it any surprise that you might get:

```
Error in 1:Qt : NA/NaN argument
```

Run something like this first:

```
Aaa <- function() {
  repeat( { ANSWER <- readline("Iterations:")
  if ( as.numeric(ANSWER)  >= 1){Qt <<- as.numeric(ANSWER)
        break} })}
```

Then run just this:

```
Aaa()
```

Then run the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks Jan. It didn't work, the reason is that the problem is not with the ANSWER variable but with the if statement. For some reason, in the fifth iteration stops working properly...

Comment: You need to describe in more detail what you mean by "it didn't work". I would also note that the code for creation of the "j" variable gives results that may not be as you intended:   `(i/3-trunc((1:5)/3))*3`  returns `[1] 10 10  7  7 7`.

Comment: With "It didn't work" I mean that when the j variable is supposed to be 3, the if function "j==3" declares it as false... But you pointed to the right place: `j<-((1:5)/3-trunc((1:5)/3))*3` should return `[1] 0 1 2 0 1` but it seems to be returning the same but unnoticeably UNROUNDED. I changed it to `j<-round((i/3-trunc(i/3))*3,1)`  and it worked!

Comment: In what part of the code is "j supposed to be 3"? You have a couple pages of code and you are not describing either the input or the desired output. You are also not responding substantively to the request to describe the goals, so I'm inclined to give up and mark the question for closure.

Comment: Jan: This is the first time I post a question and I hope I'm not being a fuss. I want j to cicle with the following values for as many iterations I want: `[1] 0 1 2 0 1 2 0`. I placed `cat("Value of j: ",j)` just before the only if statement.  When j=0 the if statement would return `j==0` as true, but when j=1 the if statement would return `j==1` as false (same thing with 2).